# front page won't change templates

Tags: templates, frontpage

I have tried changing the template of the attached page and changing which page is attached as the home page, no effect for either. The front page remains the same. I am at my wits end with this one!!

Comment: what's a attached page?

Comment: It is not a community term. I simply mean the page assigned to being the front page, as I explain later in the same sentence. I am unaware of another term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your setup for front page in `Settings > Reading` ?

Do you have `front-page.php` template in your theme? It will pretty much override anything, no matter what you choose in settings.

Comment: you truly are a paragon of acuity and a credit to the community.

Comment: BTW, the front-page.php was the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok, the question is from 9 years ago but the answer is still valid:

```
function custom_template () {
     return locate_template ('page_custom.php', false);
}
add_filter ('frontpage_template', 'custom_template');
```